# Broken Package Manager: Can't fix dependencies cause of different problem

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm a relatively inexperienced Linux user having a problem with Ubuntu LTS 14.04.1 LTS (installed from the MythBuntu DVD).

If I run 'sudo apt-get install', I see the following errors:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32gcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1) but 4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.3) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.3) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.3) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

If I run 'sudo apt-get -f install', it starts off promising, but then chokes with the following:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package mount (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mount
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not totally sure how to fix that, but whenever I run any dpkg or apt-get command that I think might help resolve the problem with mount, then it gives me errors about the unmet dependencies from above. Seems that even if I had the right approach to cleaning up mount, I couldn't execute it cause of the other errors which the problem with mount is preventing me from fixing.

How can I get package management working again?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth posting the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list for a more accurate diagnostic.

However, have you done a,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Recently ?

Comment: I had run `sudo apt-get update` recently. I ended up blowing everything on the machine away and starting over, and this problem has not resurfaced. Thanks though.